# Respecting language header in cloudflare

Tags: web, server, architecture, cdn, cloudflare

Cloudflare is caching my requests but it's ignoring the language header.

example request:

```
URL : 
https://api.example.com/v1/places/?param=1&param=2

Header : 
Accept-Language : en
```

But no matter what the `Accept-Language` value is, the first hit has the header respected (for example) `en`, when I make the same request again with another language, say `ar`, it loads english (the first language) again...

how can I make Cloudflare to respect the language for all languages (each different value), so that Cloudflare will make an entry for different languages.

or the only solution is adding the language as a query parameter?

PS: this is the page rule I'm using.

> Browser Cache TTL: 30 minutes, Cache Level: Cache Everything, Edge
> Cache TTL: a month

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They support custom cache keys via Page Rules on Enterprise plans.

https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/115004290387-Using-Custom-Cache-Keys

[image: screenshot]

Comment: On that very page it says `Additionally, you cannot include the following headers: accept-language`